# why my Hello world script doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs, so i try this script in `Index.html` like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="DEMO">
  <head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
<body>

 <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{HelloMessage}}</h1>

 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.HelloMessage = "Hello Pejman";

    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

but when i run this, it show `{{HelloMessage}}` instead of `Hello Pejman` , what is the problem?

EDIT : this is the tutorial:
[image]

Comment: check the console log for errors. AngularJS has failed to initialize but there could be many causes.

Comment: Try to add `ng-app` in the `html` or `body` tag.

Comment: Console does not show any error, this is a tutorial, i just do what it said! it works in tutorial video but it doesn't work for me!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not bootstrap angular module, that is why your code doesnt work. You must call `ng-app` in any HTML tag to notify Angular start in there. So all of the sub tags under the tag Angular declared will be able to use directives, scope, controller etc.

Please check here to understand how to create controller and use it : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

     <h1 ng-app="demo" ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{HelloMessage}}</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('demo', []);

        app.controller('HelloWorldCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.HelloMessage = "Hello Pejman";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ,this is a tutorial, i just do what it said! it works in tutorial video but it doesn't work for me!?

Comment: may it be an old tutorial? according to the newest ones it have to be like this. you are welcome! also you should assign your controller to the angular module.